# Copy-Item with over write

Tags: powershell

In one of my script, it tries to copy an exe to C:\Windows\Temp folder. For example:

```
Copy-Item repo\filename.exe -Destination \\$machine_name\C$\Windows\Temp
```

Error Message:

```
Copy-Item : The network path was not found.
At D:\CMPortal\Scripts\ClientRepair\RepairCCMClient.ps1:122 char:33
+                     if(Copy-Item <<<<  cmsetup.exe -Destination \\$install_cmexec\C$\Windows\Temp)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

When I run the same command manually, it works. Dont know whats wrong.
Is there any to overwrite the file if the copying file exists in the destination?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the quotes correctly?

```
Copy-Item 'repo\filename.exe' -Destination "\\$machine_name\C`$\Windows\Temp" -Force
```

Answer (score 1):

Does $install_cmexec contains a server name?
Also, make sure the user who runs the script has the appropriate permissions on the target path.

Comment: create a simple script that tests the existent of that folder (test-path $path) and run it under the same credentials, any good?

Comment: The folder exists as it is part of the OS.

Comment: The question is if the calling user see it.